# How do I get the body from an HttpWebResponse using Visual Basic (VS2017)

Tags: json, vb.net, rest, visual-studio-2017

I am having a hell of a time with this project I am working on and could really use your help. I'll try to keep this as concise as possible.
Basically, I have a UI setup that collects user information and sends `REST API` calls to my call control system. Currently it is working in regards to adding lines, trunks etc.

The problem is I want to see the body of the response coming back from the server. If I have the exception handling look for an `OK` status code and turn an indicator green, it performs as I have asked.
But I cannot get it to give me the full body of the response like it does when I send the call in `POSTMAN`.

Here is the response I get back in `POSTMAN` and would like to get back when I make the API call in VB. I get a `Status Code 400` with this in the body.

> {
>       "hint": "The specified Pattern (2952) is already in use by the line owner.",
>       "details": "Conflicting Pattern",
>       "code": "P0001",
>       "message": "invalid_parameter" }

I have tried every combination of search criteria I could find on this site and nothing seems to be working for me. I just don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is a sample of how the request/response is set up now.

```
Try
    '//Setup HTTP connection and modify headers
    Dim APIRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://" & CMIP.Text & "/api/v1/" & Custom_Endpoint_URL.Text)
    APIRequest.Method = "POST"
    APIRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + LatestToken.Text)
    APIRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    'WebCall.Headers.Add("Prefer", "return=representation") 'Only used for testing purposes

    '//Prepare JSON request
    Dim bytearray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Custom_Body.Text)
    APIRequest.ContentLength = bytearray.Length

    '//Bypass self-signed cert issue
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

    '//Load JSON payload into datastream
    Dim datastream As Stream = APIRequest.GetRequestStream()
    datastream.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)

    ''//Response
    Dim response As WebResponse = APIRequest.GetResponse
    Dim responsestream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
    Dim responsereader As New StreamReader(responsestream)
    Dim responsereadstring As String = responsereader.ReadToEnd

    '//Send response to results window
    Response_Box.Text = responsereadstring

Catch ex As WebException

End Try
```

I wanted to figure this out on my own but I have been at this for a few days now and I'm at the point I am banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` method throws a `WebException` when the response has a status code in the 4xx or 5xx range.  Based on the information in your question, your API call is returning a status code of 400, so that would trigger the exception.  Your `Catch` block is completely empty, so you are silently ignoring this case.  (That is why you should never leave your `Catch` blocks empty-- you'll never know that something is failing.)

It turns out that the `WebException` class has a `Response` property on it (as well as `Status`), so you can get the data from there.  You just need to fill in the `Catch` block:

```
    Catch ex As WebException

        Dim responsestream As Stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream
        Dim responsereader As New StreamReader(responsestream)
        Dim responsereadstring As String = responsereader.ReadToEnd
        Response_Box.Text = responsereadstring

    End Try
```

Comment: I am now able to catch both successful and unsuccessful responses. In the case of a '400 Bad Request', I am using that 'WebException.Response property' to pull the same JSON body I was get in 'POSTMAN'

I have marked your answer as accepted. Thank you.